# PHP: Is there no way to use a global variable inside an object constructor?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, global

I have a php script that is intended to be user-editable, with some options set right at the beginning, including allowable extensions for image files.

Later on, I want to use this in an object constructor to set whether a file is an image or not.

```
$extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];

class directory_entry {

  function __construct($name) {

    $this->name = $name;

    $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $this->is_image = in_array(strtoupper($extension), $extensions); // throws an error

    $this->image = $this->is_image($name);

  }
}
```

This doesn't work because I can't call `$extensions` from inside an class(?). Is there a way to do it without including `$extensions` in every object of this class? Seems nuts to declare objects with

`$files[] = new directory_entry($value, $extensions);`

and have every instance of this class have a copy of the same array?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: You don't necessarily have to inject the `$extensions` variable itself, but you could inject a class like a `SettingsProvider` or something which could contain it, and many other common settings for your app

Comment: @aynber Yes! That's what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that seems to work best for what I'm trying to do (bear in mind that I'm a PHP and OOP n00b) is the [globals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword:

```
$extensions = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];

class directory_entry {

  function __construct($name) {

    $this->name = $name;

    $extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    global $extensions; //use the global version of $extensions
    $this->is_image = in_array(strtoupper($extension), $extensions); // works!

    $this->image = $this->is_image($name);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a classe for this?

```
class ExtensionsEnum
{
    const IMAGES = ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png"];
}
```

Then

```
use ExtensionsEnum;

class directory_entry {
...
    $this->is_image = in_array(strtoupper($extension), ExtensionsEnum::IMAGES); // throws an error
...
}
```

Comment: Arrays in const are supported since PHP 5.6+